# `string-match' and `match-string' in Emacs Lisp

Tags: regular-expressions

I try to understand the functions `match-string` and `string-match` in Emacs Lisp.

The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Simple-Match-Data.html) provides what seems to be (?) a reproducible example:

```lisp
     (string-match "\\(qu\\)\\(ick\\)"
                   "The quick fox jumped quickly.")
                   ;0123456789
          ⇒ 4
     
     (match-string 0 "The quick fox jumped quickly.")
          ⇒ "quick"
```

But this is not what I get if I try to execute those instructions. If I simply copy-paste them into a buffer and execute them with `C-x C-e`, the first one is OK and actually returns 4, but the second one triggers an error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (args-out-of-range "The quick fox jumped quickly." 341 341)
  match-string(0 "The quick fox jumped quickly.")
  eval((match-string 0 "The quick fox jumped quickly.") nil)
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

All the following examples presented in the manual also trigger similar errors.

I'm using Emacs 26.3. Is there a subtlety I don't understand (e.g., should `match-string` be called in a specific context)?

Comment: Also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40896

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info